# iPHone X support for native-base theme

Tags: react-native, native-base

Given my code for formatting react-native page component using native-base is follows :

```
.. <Container>
<Content>
...
<Content>

</Container>
```

With following :

```
"dependencies": {
    ..
    "firebase": "^4.11.0",
    "immutable": "^3.8.2",
    ..
    "native-base": "2.3.10",
    "native-echarts": "^0.4.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.0",
    "react": "16.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.52.0",

  }
```

When it comes to  execution on iPhone X simulator  , it turns below :

[image]

Could you please tell me which method I can pursue to get rid of the black spaces at the top and bottom ?

Comment: Set splash screen for iPhone X. It will fix issue.

Comment: Thanks. IS there a way to create splash for Android as well ?